# Как выгрузить ресурс в папку? C#

Tags: c#, resources

Подскажите как мне выгрузить ресурс в папку.
Пример:
Я добавил ttf в ресурсы, как мне ее скинуть на рабочий стол?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так как ресурс бинарный, то можно реализовать так:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\font.ttf", ProjectName.Properties.Resources.font);
```

Answer (score 3):

Есть еще одно, достаточно [неплохое решение (взято на en SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19982104/5275890), немного модернизировал:

```
// fileName - это полный путь с именем файла
public void SaveResource(string resourceName, string fileName)
{
    using (var resource = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    {
        using (var file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            resource?.CopyTo(file);
        }
    }
}
```

И, кстати, у Вас решение для бинарных файлов, для тестового к примеру вот так:

```
File.WriteAllText(fileName, Properties.Resources.file);
```

И, еще будет полезно, если это картинка, то у ресурса будет метод `.Save(string filename)`, к примеру если добавить в ресурсы `img.jpg`, то будет так:

```
Properties.Resources.img.Save("--путь--\\img.jpg");
```

Можно сохранить в указанное место.

Answer (score 0):

В простейшем случае, когда ресурс добавлен как элемент проекта (с параметром Embedded Resource), как-то так:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
...

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //имя ресурса: складывается из имени сборки и имени файла
    string resname = "MyApplication.file.ttf";

    Assembly ass = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    string[] names = ass.GetManifestResourceNames();//получаем все ресурсы

    foreach (string name in names)
    {
        if (name == resname) //находим нужный ресурс
        {
            //открываем поток для чтения данных
            Stream s = ass.GetManifestResourceStream(name);                    
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(textBox1.Text + "file.ttf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

            //записываем данные в файл
            using (s)
            using (fs)
            {
                s.CopyTo(fs);
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Если ресурс добавляется не как элемент проекта, а через вкладку "Ресурсы" в свойствах проекта, для его извлечения из коллекции ресурсов понадобится использовать класс [ResourceReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.resources.resourcereader(v=vs.110).aspx)