# Вывести файл из ресурсов в папку на C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, resources, export

В общем, есть textBox1 и бутон в textBox1 должны писать директорию папки, в моем случае C:\Users\1\Desktop\123 , а при нажатии на бутон из ресурсов программы должна копироваться картинка png12.png в эту папку, есть вот такой код, который я нашел,не робит, подскажите, в чем проблема?Находил различные статьи, но ничего не работаетЪ

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string dir = textBox1.Text;
            string FilePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\png12.png";
            if (!File.Exists(FilePath))
            {
                File.Copy(dir, FilePath, true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Как обычно бывает, сам и нашел ответ, в общем вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/620437/Как-выгрузить-ресурс-в-папку-c?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Вот мое решение с помощью потоков, но можешь использовать сахар using для Idisposable:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dir = textBox1.Text;
        string filePath = Application.StartupPath+ "\\Слайд1.png";
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            Image.FromFile(filePath).Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            FileStream file = new FileStream(dir + "file.png", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            ms.WriteTo(file);
            file.Close();
            ms.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            ms.Close();
        }            
    }
```